# Mechanize not logging in to site properly

Tags: python, mechanize

After spending the best part of 3 hours getting nowhere, i thought i would ask a question myself.
i am using python and `mechanize`'s `Browser`. I am trying to login to my home router. i can get to the login page, fill the password field (eg `br.form['password'] = 'mypassword'` etc), but now i am stuck because no matter what i try, i always get sent to a page saying i am forbidden/session has timed out i am handling cookies with a cookie jar, i have handled robots, but it still doesnt love me enough to let me login.... help?
if you have any suggestions as to why i can not login successfully, please, please, please share xxx

**EDIT:**

it does have javascript, but i am simulating it

```
**EDIT2:**
```

i just realized that the javascript i am simulating is for pressing the disconnect button on the previous page...... probably fix my problem if i emulate the javascript for this page ......

i am faking the user agent

i will have a look w/ wireshark xxx

ps thanks for replying so fast xx

UPDATE:
sigh. i think it may just be one of those things where you just have to say f it and move on because i am emulating the javascript it needed exactly as it is done (just checking, MD5 == hashlib.md5("...").hexdigest()?).... thanks anyway people xxx

Comment: Look at the traffic on the wire with wireshark with both a web browser successful login and your mechanism failing login?

Comment: @sarnold: isn't wireshark a bit overkill? webkit's developers tools or firefox's firebug should allow to see what's happing.

Comment: @tokland: No, they are not. They can only show data sent and received by the browser, but not data sent and received by Mechanize.

Comment: Maybe the server is checking user agent. Try faking some regular browser. Some servers are also checking `Referer` header, so you may want to fake that too.

Comment: @sarnold: oh, well, to see what mechanize is doing, ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have to deal with Javascript, I'd try to use [WebDriver](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/PythonBindings). It has Python bindings and it's not that hard to use.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some sample code for mechanize implementing cookies and a fake user-agent -- might help out...

```
import mechanize

cookies = mechanize.CookieJar()
opener = mechanize.build_opener(mechanize.HTTPCookieProcessor(cookies))
opener.addheaders = [("User-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10_6; en-us) AppleWebKit/533.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.1 Safari/533.4"),]
mechanize.install_opener(opener)

url = "http://your_home_router_address"
content = mechanize.urlopen(url)
return content.read()
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure there is no Javascript in the page, manipulating cookies or other headers ?

I had those kind of problems with some (certainly not Web 2.0 :-) web sites, and had to analyze and emulate those scripts somehow... :-q